# Creating android background service NO GUI in python

Tags: android, python, background, boot

This is a further question based on one of my previous questions. [Creating an android service to run in the background using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410562/creating-an-android-service-to-run-in-the-background-using-python) I have looked at the recommendations made but I now wonder if it is possible to create the background service in python for android with no gui so it is almost like a passive service. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Services don't have any GUI ...

Comment: from my understanding to start the service it requires a gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to write a service for Android in Python. But you can maybe start your service using a BroadcastReceiver at boot time.You could register your broadcast receiver to filter intents with  Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: do you have any links or example code that i could see (this is my first time developing for android so I am not fully sure how things should be set out i have read guides online but they are mostly in java)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460941/broadcast-receiver-not-receiving-action-boot-completed. You have to read both question and answer

Comment: So correct me if i'm wrong but i would only need the <receiver> portion of that code for it to start on boot?

Comment: Correct!! You also need a class which extends BroadcastReceiver. Here is a tutorial on how to create a BroadcastReceiver http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html