# Start Android Service on boot time Android 4.0

Tags: android, service, time, device, boot

I'm triying to start a android service in android 4.0 when the device is booting, in boot time, but it's imposible , I had be used many codes, copy and paste. I had used code from here, stackoverflow of others examples and questions , but for me is imposible. I'm using android 4.0.1 in a table Acer Iconia A501. I put my code here. Somebody Can it try this code??? this is the page :[This page please, it is easy](http://ambellido.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/iniciar-un-servicio-en-android-al.html)

Comment: If you're so sure it's impossible, then what question is there to answer?  Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: can you please edit your question and add your code

Comment: I have this same code in my app and at startup on a Razr XT910 phone with 4.04 android it boots up and starts both my apps just fine.  Please add your Manifest xml code and your BootupReciever code

Comment: I cant reach personal blogs from where I am at.

Comment: please be sure to check the manifest very carefully.  AND when running the code, goto Window --> ShowView -->Logcat and tell us if you see any errors there.  But first make sure you are getting the BOOT_COMPLETE.  You can just issue notification or log to check this.

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Don't try to start a service until you are certain you are receiving the BOOT_COMPLETE.  Then make sure you are seeing the log file before you try to connect to service so you can check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a broadcast receiver for the intent that is broadcast on startup. There is ZERO doubt that this is what you need to do.

See:  [BroadcastReceiver not receiving BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed)

You need to do the same.  Register a broadcast receiver and first make sure that you are catching the BOOT_COMPLETED event.   Then its just a matter of doing a startService.

The problem is most likely in the Manifest.  Check that you have exactly the right name for everything. Note the .  in names like .MyBroadcastReceiver  These are important. Missing just one thing will cause a problem.

Both the Receiver and Service definition must be perfect.  Also check logcat and tell us what errors are there.