# Service does not launch after install?

Tags: android

I have followed the tutorial here :
http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/09/14/android/starting-an-android-service-after-boot/

about creating a service, which is activating after boot of Android.
Anyway It practically never started.
I found in here : [How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time)
that it is not anymore possible since Android 3.0+.

My question is :

- How to start a boot service once installed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start Android Service 4.0 boot time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640800/start-android-service-4-0-boot-time)

Comment: your first link returns a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how to start manually a service, since it does not have any visual elements ?

Add "visual elements", in the form of an activity.

You need an activity anyway, for:

- Settings for managing the behavior of this service
- Help and instructions for getting support
- License agreement

So, write the activity. After the user has launched your activity, your manifest-registered `BroadcastReceivers`, such as your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver, will work again on Android 3.1+ devices.

Comment: Thank You very much CommonsWare. :)

Answer (score 1):

In lates android versions you can launch on boot only when user manually started application.

Comment: I see, but how to start manually a service, since it does not have any visual elements ?

Comment: So far I have listed a few of tens of examples in here, but none related to the issue. Could you link some ?