# BOOT COMPLETE is not working in Android (Redmi)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I am currently working on a application which includes Boot_Completed Broadcast receiver concept. I have tested this app in my **Motorola Moto G** Phone. The app runs fine and shows the Toast message. But when I test this app in **XIAOMI Redmi 1S** phone it doesn't show the Toast message.

I have already seen many questions similar to my issue (like these -  [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed), etc.) ... But I haven't got any solution to this problem.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demoapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:installLocation="internalOnly" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.demoapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.demoapp.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 </application>
 </manifest>
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is your PACKAGE_NAME?? and source MyReceiver package names??

Comment: "com.example.demoapp" is my PACKAGE_NAME. @kalyanpvs

Comment: Facing same issue with Xiaomi Redmi 1s.

Comment: then change it in manifest like **package="com.example.demoapp"** and is Myreceiver is class path is "com.example.demoapp.MyReceiver"??

Comment: I change this but not worked. @kalyanpvs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is solution for your bug.

What you need to do is that , you need to mention this permission also in your Intent-Filter.

```
               <receiver android:name="com.example.demoapp.MyReceiver"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:exported="true" >

               <intent-filter >
                       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                       <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
               </intent-filter>
               </receiver>
```

Here you need to do one thing also.

Go to "Settings-Apps_open your app info-Manage permisson" in yourdevice

Here check all things here.

Because for some devices it will not work.
Ex.Red mi

Try this !

Comment: This worked as a solution to my Redmi 1s problem. Thanks Jay for the info.

Comment: Adding <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/> didn`t helpl me with Redmi 1s.
It only worked after a added my app in the Auto-Restart app list in the Security App provided by the MIUI.

Comment: Its not working in my Xiaomi Note 10 lite

Answer (score 7):

in case of XIOMI devices you have to manually set permission, i think you can solve this by adding your app in "auto-start management" list, which is available as default security app.

Comment: How to add my app in "auto-start management" list? @user3188965

Answer (score 2):

Go to manage app permission

Select your app from apps

toggle "Auto-Start"

done

Answer (score 1):

try removing if condition from broadcast reciever

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```