# start application after android system is loaded

Tags: android

I want to make start video playing automatically after android system is loaded. I have tried many different code snippets but doesn't worked for me. my android os version is 2.3.4.

**Receive.java**

```java
package com.android.fireup;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, PlayVideo.class));
    }
}
```

**PlayVideo.java**

```java
package com.android.fireup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayVideo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.y;
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        //videoView.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/y.mp4");
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.fireup" 
android:installLocation="internalOnly">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name=".Receive"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".PlayVideo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Now it starts playing at startup and plays normally.**

I changed code in **PlayVideo.java**, relocated media file in **raw** directory.

```java
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.y;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

and in **Receive.java** changed to:

```java
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, PlayVideo.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, PlayVideo.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i); 
    }
}
```

Also:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Receive"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <!--QUICKBOOT_POWERON for HTC-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Depending on your device:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You may also need to look at using this instead of "/mnt/sdcard"

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

Comment: it says can't play video.
after this i changed line :

<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
to
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK" />

But nothing.

I use internal storage.

Comment: Does it play if you launch the app normally?

Answer (score 1):

The `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver is the right way to go and as far as I can see the is no big error in your code. Some suggestion though:

- HTC devices might require `com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` in the intent filter instead of `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` so add both (i.e. having two `<action android:name="..."`)
- it's recommended to add the category `android.intent.category.HOME`
- note that the `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver only works, if the app is in status active. Check this [nice SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed) for details.

Comment: My phone is Motorola Droid 3

Comment: Ok, so either your app isn't `active` or you need to add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag (as Sheldon noted) or both ;)

Comment: Note that it's recommended to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"y.mp4"` instead of `"/mnt/sdcard/y.mp4"` and you have to add permissions for reading external storage (`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

Comment: I've added external storage, edited manifest file and getting error: 
The application has stopped unexpectedly and one another message :
Sorry, this video cannot be played.
I think storage is not ready for second one.

Comment: Please add a full stacktrace from your logcat in your question; otherwise it's hard to guess ....