# Boot completed broadcast not being received after reinstall

Tags: android, uninstallation, bootcompleted

We have an android application (A) that runs with system permissions. Its job is to download and install another application (B). As soon as A installs B, it automatically launches B.

Application B runs on boot.

The first time app A installs app B, everything works fine, and B runs every time the device reboots. Similarly, if App A overwrites B by installing a newer version, everything still functions.

The problem we're having is **if a user manually uninstalls B** through the android settings menu, when A next installs (and runs) B, B does not restart after the device reboots.

The problem looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed), but the Application *does* get run (by the system app A) as soon as it's installed. The whole process *works* if the application has not been uninstalled in the past, so it currently appears to be something to do with the uninstall process itself.

We have also tried manually sending a `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent with `--include-stopped-packages` set to no avail.

Any pointers appreciated.