# Best way to create a recurrent thread that get data from Web API?

Tags: java, android, service, alarm

What's the best approach on Android to create a recurrent thread that get data from Web Api and notify user when event happen?

I was using a Alarm Manager that call an Intent Service but looks like this is not the best. It dies when the system is rebooted.

Does anybody have a good reccomandation?

Comment: See solution dude

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1>0){
    Result r = getResultFromAPI(args);
    processResults(r);
    Thread.sleep(sleepTimeInMillis);
}
```

also if you have access to modify the service you can set it up to do push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented via Android Service.

Benefits of Android Service with START_STICKY

- Android will take responsibility to start your service again if stopped by any reason.
- Below service runs on worker thread which will never hang your app.
- get data api will never be call twice if in process. (flag maintained)

I implemented this class in my location tracking app. which you can just paste and use.

```
package in.kpis.tracker.projectClasses.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


/**
 * Created by KHEMRAJ on 1/24/2018.
 */

public class SyncLocationServiceSample extends Service {
    public String TAG = "SyncLocationService";
    private Thread mThread;
    ScheduledExecutorService worker;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (worker == null) worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        if (mThread == null || !mThread.isAlive()) {
            mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    syncLocationAPI();
                    if (worker != null) {
   // 60 * 1000 is 60 second, change it as your requirement.
                        worker.schedule(this, 60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }
                }
            });
            mThread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopThread();
    }

    boolean apiCalling = false;

    private synchronized void syncLocationAPI() {
        if (apiCalling) return;
//        do your api call here.
// make apiCalling true when you call api, and apiCalling  false when response come
    }

    private void stopThread() {
        worker = null;
        if (mThread != null && mThread.isAlive()) mThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

**Things to be consider**

You will start this service with an device boot complete receiver. [How to make boot complete receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19856267/6891563). Let me know if you need help for starting service.

Comment: My solution is actually similar. I just have an IntentService that use internally an AlarmManager to wake up. But it crashes when I try to start the service from the boot. I think that is it because of Android Oreo, but I can't find any solution

Comment: Dude IntentService is not reliable for this type of requirement

Comment: Use this service and let me know if you find any issue. Because this is working well in my location tracking app, which needs a reliable service.

Comment: you can not start intent service as start sticky, for long thread above service is recommended

Comment: it works, the problem was actually with android O that basically want a Foreground Service. But anyway I appreciated your solution