# I cannot run any code on boot completed on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I researched in order to find out the way to make my app do something on device boot. I tried to do the same but it does not seem to work. I tried with several methods but I am finding some unexpected problems.
Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ignacio.dailynotification">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And here is my broadcast receiver BootCompletedReceiver:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String LOG_TAG = BootCompletedReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

    String message = "BootCompletedReceiver onReceive, action is " + action;

    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, action);

    if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "phone restarted",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"phone restarted");

    }
}
}
```

Now I am getting this output in my logcat when searching for 'bootcompleted':

```
2019-09-20 07:52:56.776 1867-2017/? I/keyguard:     AsusSlideshowManager:queryLocalList cursor null mBootCompleted:false mRetryQuery:0
2019-09-20 07:52:57.291 1867-2017/? I/keyguard: AsusSlideshowManager:queryLocalList cursor null mBootCompleted:false mRetryQuery:0
2019-09-20 07:52:58.303 1867-2017/? I/keyguard: AsusSlideshowManager:queryLocalList cursor null mBootCompleted:false mRetryQuery:0
2019-09-20 07:53:00.491 1867-1867/? I/keyguard: AsusWeatherDataMonitor: :onBootCompleted
2019-09-20 07:53:16.910 2144-2144/? E/VvmBootCompletedRcvr: phone account ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [e0184adedf913b076626646d3f52c3b49c39ad6d], UserHandle{0} has invalid subId -1
2019-09-20 07:53:17.326 1435-2416/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4147:com.android.vending/u0a47 for broadcast com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.boothandler.BootCompletedReceiver duration: 14
2019-09-20 07:53:19.716 1435-2027/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc    4313:com.asus.dm/1000 for broadcast com.asus.dm/.BootCompletedReceiver duration: 21
2019-09-20 07:53:19.836 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: ===== BCReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 cmp=com.asus.dm/.BootCompletedReceiver (has extras) }
2019-09-20 07:53:19.935 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: check fota update status.
2019-09-20 07:53:19.935 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: check unfinished dm session.
2019-09-20 07:53:19.935 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: check is need resume DL.
2019-09-20 07:53:19.935 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: ===== over 18 month, no fota polling @receiveBootComplete()
2019-09-20 07:53:19.936 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: NextPollingInterval: Long.MAX_VALUE
2019-09-20 07:53:19.936 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: **NOT** Start DM Service
2019-09-20 07:53:19.937 4313-4313/? D/DMC->BootCompletedReceiver: exit onReceive
2019-09-20 07:53:19.938 4313-4313/? I/ActivityThread: Performing receive of Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 cmp=com.asus.dm/.BootCompletedReceiver (has extras) }: app=com.asus.dm.DMApp@a04c4e4, appName=com.asus.dm, pkg=com.asus.dm, comp={com.asus.dm/com.asus.dm.BootCompletedReceiver}, dir=/system/app/DMClient/DMClient.apk, duration=102
2019-09-20 07:53:21.696 4423-4423/? D/FirmwareManager: Booted - onBootCompleted, check for PAD EC and Camera ISP
2019-09-20 07:53:24.792 1435-2706/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4686:com.asus.userfeedback/u0a108 for broadcast com.asus.userfeedback/.BootCompletedBroadcastReceiver duration: 18
2019-09-20 07:53:25.721 1435-1435/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1357 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:620 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:620 com.dsi.ant.server.AntService.startService:129 com.dsi.ant.server.startup.BootCompletedReceiver.onReceive:41 
2019-09-20 07:53:26.169 1435-2416/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.libraries.internal.growth.growthkit.inject.GrowthKitBootCompletedBroadcastReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED due to sender null (uid 1000)
2019-09-20 07:53:34.828 5190-5190/? W/GrowthKit: Failed to get GrowthKitJobScheduler in GrowthKitBootCompletedBroadcastReceiver So GrowthKit failed to schedule jobs after package replaced / boot completed.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to get GrowthKit Component from host app.
    at com.google.android.libraries.internal.growth.growthkit.inject.GrowthKit.get(GrowthKit.java:43)
    at com.google.android.libraries.internal.growth.growthkit.inject.GrowthKitBootCompletedBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GrowthKitBootCompletedBroadcastReceiver.java:29)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3044)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1561)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6139)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
2019-09-20 07:53:40.272 2820-5535/? I/constellation: [intent_handler] Received onBootCompleted intent
2019-09-20 07:53:43.700 2254-5354/? I/NetRec: [145] BootCompletedOrAppUpdatedIntentOperation.onHandleIntent: onBootCompleted()
2019-09-20 07:53:43.948 2254-5354/? I/NetRec: [145] BootCompletedOrAppUpdatedIntentOperation.onHandleIntent: Scheduling CleanupDatabaseTask
2019-09-20 07:53:46.769 1435-1453/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 5946:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service/1000 for broadcast org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service/.SmartcardServiceBootCompletedBroadcastReceiver duration: 17
```

I think maybe I am getting the broadcast properly received but my app cannot do anything beyond that or so it seems.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: check out this ;;;; <receiver
            android:name=".Receivers.BootRecoverReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Maybe this post can help you : [BroadcastReceiver not receiving BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed)

Comment: @EliasFazel Thanks for your comment. I tried with that, but it is still not working and I get mostly the same output in the logcat. Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 (has extras) } .....etc
2019-09-23 09:44:10.780 5663-5663/? W/GrowthKit: Failed to get GrowthKitJobScheduler in GrowthKitBootCompletedBroadcastReceiver So GrowthKit failed to schedule jobs after package replaced / boot completed.
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to get GrowthKit Component from host app.  ......etc

Comment: Actually I am not even getting any log message from the onReceive function (let alone checking the action's name etc) on boot. I tried as well with the action POWER_DISCONNECTED and I am getting the proper message on disconnecting and connecting the charging cable from the phone.

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
   public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "phone restarted",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"phone restarted");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is not working though, that is pretty much the same I have. Could you show me what would I need for the Manifest, etc other problems that could be keeping my phone from receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just need this `<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: Thanks for that, it is a simplified version of what I had. But it does not work either.